# Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.swapComponent is not a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, axios, inertiajs

I am developing an application using Laravel with Jetsream and the  Vuejs & Inertia stack and am getting a blank page across my application after running `npm audit fix`.

I ran the npm command `npm audit fix` after receiving a message that there were 3 high severity vulnerabilities. This was the output:

```
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN @inertiajs/inertia-vue@0.2.4 requires a peer of @inertiajs/inertia@^0.2.0 || ^0.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ axios@0.21.1
+ @inertiajs/inertia@0.8.2
added 4 packages from 5 contributors and updated 2 packages in 4.307s

55 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 2 of 3 vulnerabilities in 1150 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

Since running that command, every page on the site is blank and has the following error showing in the console:

```
app.js:121 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.swapComponent is not a function
    at app.js:121
(anonymous) @ app.js:121
Promise.then (async)
setPage @ app.js:121
handleInitialPageVisit @ app.js:121
init @ app.js:121
created @ app.js:108
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:104023
callHook @ app.js:106380
Vue._init @ app.js:107162
VueComponent @ app.js:107307
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ app.js:105450
init @ app.js:105281
createComponent @ app.js:108133
createElm @ app.js:108080
patch @ app.js:108669
Vue._update @ app.js:106106
updateComponent @ app.js:106227
get @ app.js:106638
Watcher @ app.js:106627
mountComponent @ app.js:106234
./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount @ app.js:111204
./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount @ app.js:114104
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:120619
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
0 @ app.js:120679
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:84
(anonymous) @ app.js:87
```

I am new to laravel/this stack and any help tracking down the source of this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I am facing the same issue when I upgraded

from:

```
"@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.1.9",
```

to

```
"@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.8.2",
```

Since it was suggested by GitHub security audit, so for now I just revert back to `^0.1.9`

Answer (score 3):

Try update the package `@inertiajs/inertia-vue` to last version "^0.5.4".

In package.json set "@inertiajs/inertia-vue": "^0.5.4" and run `npm install`.

Work from me!

Comment: Unforitually It did not work for me :( I had to revert back. I will look at the new Laravel Jetstream update included in v2 and see if I can work on a fix for my own issue.

Comment: I tried this and it removed the error listed above, but my project is still broken and I am getting several other console errors to the effect of ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined``` with any and all ```$page``` variables/props etc.. I am not sure exactly what's going on but seems that vue is not working properly, I have tried updating all of the packages o the most current version with no luck.

Comment: This combo worked for me: inertia: ^0.8.4 and inertia-vue: ^0.5.5

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem after npm update and to fix it I have downgraded inertia package. In package.json "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.1.7" then npm install.